# How to get all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

this code i have only gets current item that are added, but i want to get all items that are created,

```
ntext.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {


            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();


            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>'
                + fromTime.toISOString() + '</Value></Gt><Gt><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTime.toISOString() +
                '</Value></Gt></And></Where></Query></View>');
            this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
            context.load(collListItem);
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var listDetails = oListItem.get_item('EventDate') +"      " + oListItem.get_item('EndDate');
                result = result + listDetails;

                alert(result);

            }
```

Comment: You mean all items in the list?

Comment: Yes and only display date and time to and from

Comment: I want first to display are items that are created in the list, but i also want to display Dates and times that are free to add in calender list @AmalHashim

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem, 'Include(EventDate,EndDate)');
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    var listDetails = oListItem.get_item('EventDate') +"      " + oListItem.get_item('EndDate');
    result = result + listDetails;
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Alright how could i then display for the user available free dates to add in the calender list in an range 5 days based on want the user has added in my textboxes from and to date?